# Google Chrome Push Notifications not working if the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

It is written [here](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) that the push notifications will work even if the browser is closed, but I tested it and it is not the case. I receive push-notifications only if the browser is open (doesnt matter if the particular webpage is open or not).

I tested this on chrome for Desktop & chrome for Android (after updating to latest version).

my question is :-  For push notifications to work should the browser be open?

Note:- I used [this](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/) for testing.

Comment: I have tested the link you provided and it works well. Tested by opening the website, allowing for push notifications, closing Chrome and then triggering a push request using curl.

Comment: @KevinFarrugia on which platform did you test? I had tested on windows 10 and Android M. For me it didnt work when the browser was closed.

Comment: Tested on Android M

Comment: The other comments suggest that on Android, Chrome and Firefox will show push notifications even if the browsers are closed, but in my experience what can happen is that the notifications will arrive, but only appear once the browser is reopened (Chrome for Android 80, Firefox for Android 68). Certainly doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: Well, it seems the situation is same for most platforms. On mobile devices, android, no requirement for browser to be open to receive push notificaitons, but on desktop oss a running browser is necessary.
It would be great if on desktop oss, and others, too the reception of the push messages could be handled by a platform's own service related to background tasks or push notifications jobs then handed to web service workers (waking them up if needed) so that we don't need a running browser at that time. It is the case in android via Google Play Services, afaik.

Answer (score 19):

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api), Chrome and Firefox desktop browsers require the browser to be running for receiving push notifications; mobile browsers typically don't.

Comment: Same is the case for Microsoft Edge (Chromium based) on the desktop.

Answer (score 6):

**Open Settings** (in chrome)

Do the following:

```
> advanced 
    > system >
        "continue running background apps when chrome is closed" 
             >enable
```

Answer (score 5):

On desktop, browsers need a process running. For example on Mac OS X the browser can have no window open but if you look at the dock, the light underneath icon can be glowing (meaning it has a process running). In the scenario you should receive push messages.

If the browser was completely quit, then push messages won't get through.

The same applies to windows and Linux.

On android you should be receiving the messages regardless of whether the browser is open or not. This is in part (as far as I know) to the fact that android manages it's connection to the push service rather than the browser, so it'll receive messages whenever possible.

Comment: thanks Matt for the answer and Push notification online demos ...Is this still applied for 2019?

Comment: I believe this is still the case yes.

Answer (score 4):

The messages should (eventually) get through even if they are sent while the browser is closed, or the device is offline, etc. (And this works for me using https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/ and other tests.)

Comment: thx, I can confirm this works with Chrome 85.  The (previously sent) notification will be delivered when the browser is started or reconnected to the network.

Answer (score 4):

I've worked on demo to provide push notifications on Google Chrome and Firefox. Demo -> https://twitter.com/d_danailov/status/1163824171480166400

If someone has a question could ping me on twitter.

The public URL: https://push-notifications-ddanailov.firebaseapp.com/

Repo: https://github.com/dimitardanailov/push-notifications

[image: Push notifications]

Comment: Hello Sir, Does this send notifications even if browser closed?

Comment: Please use the demo project to test my setup. I've worked on this project before 3.5 years. I'm almost sure: The notification must be displayed on the notification section of your Mac / Windows or Linux workstation.

Answer (score 1):

On desktop the browser needs to be running since that is the process that receives the push messages. Some extensions, like hangouts force the browser to keep running even when the last tab is closed so for users with one such extension installed push will work all the time.

On Android, the browser does not need to be running since the entity in charge of receiving the messages is baked into Google Play Services.

The Chrome team is working on the desktop issue in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402456

Answer (score 1):

<s>It is possible to write Chrome extension where [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) can run if Chrome is allowed to run in the background (configurable in settings). It can also [use GCM](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm).</s>

EDIT:

For service worker to run in the background even if no tab or window is opened there must be at least one Chrome extension with `background` permissions installed and Chrome must be allowed to run apps in background. Tested on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the other users are right and there is no way to receive them on Windows if the browser is closed *unless the browser is running in the background, which some Chrome Apps and Extensions can force*. I ran into this recently and found this extension, which I believe may help. It keeps the browser running in the background even if the windows are closed but does not do anything besides that (it is open source and presumably the version uploaded to the Chrome Store matches that version)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightning-reopen/ahphokgmcecbjeipkfkamcdmemghkaph