# What if I close a tab during chrome extension popup working?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that read a current tab's content and does a heavy task on backend. What if I close a tab during its process? I'd like to allow a user to close tab without waiting for a process to finish. My code is like below. It is written in React and Typescript. Thank you in advance.

```js
import React from 'react';

export const PopupPage = () => {
  const doTask = async(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    chrome.tabs?.query({
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    }, async tabs => {
      const currentTab = tabs[0]
      const currentUrl = currentTab.url
      const currentTitle = currentTab.title
      if (currentUrl === undefined) {
        return
      }
      const creationOptions = {
        type: 'basic' as chrome.notifications.TemplateType,
        title: `Nice title`,
        message: `Start a heavy process`,
        iconUrl: './logo.png',
        contextMessage: 'You can close the tab now.'
      } as chrome.notifications.NotificationOptions<true>;

      chrome.notifications.create(currentUrl, creationOptions)
      
      // Send a url and title to backend and wait for it finishing.
      await executeHeavyTaskAndWaitForResponseFromBackend(currentUrl, currentTitle)

      const updateOptions = 
        {
          type: 'basic' as chrome.notifications.TemplateType,
          title: 'Nice Title',
          message: "COMPLETED",
          iconUrl: './logo.png'
        }
        // I want to be sure this notification is called even after the tab is closed
        chrome.notifications.create(currentUrl, updateOptions)
    }); 
  }
  return <button onClick={doTask}>Do a heavy task</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [background service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/), it listens on events (you can trigger it in your `doTask` function) and will not unload until it goes idle (finished all tasks).

You can load the service worker by calling `runtime.getBackgroundPage` or via sending a message ([message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/)).

Comment: Thanks. So is it impossible in an action? I've searched but couldn't find relevant resources about closing tab during a process.

Comment: Yes, you can trigger it in an action. Closing a tab won't affect a service worker. However, if you mean terminating the whole browser, you should probably look at [Does service worker runs on background even if browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201067/does-service-worker-runs-on-background-even-if-browser-is-closed) 

But you can simply try it out if a service worker will keep a background process running after window closing. If the worker terminates, you could also persist states by using the storage API.

Comment: Thank you. I confirmed when closing popup or switching between tabs, popup process gets terminated (by seeing if it changes badgetext even after closing tabs). I'll use Event Page available from Manifest V3