# Push notification does not work when browser close

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working with service worker to use push-notification and build PWA. I understood that push-notifications will work even if the browser is closed. But after severals tests I discovered that it is not the case.
I tested with the browser of my **desktop** and I receive notifications only if the browser is open.
I also tested with **android** smartphone and I received notification only if my browser is open or if I left it to go to another application on my phone. As soon as, I closed my smartphone browser notification didn't work.

I found a post form 2 year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034950/google-chrome-push-notifications-not-working-if-the-browser-is-closed). It said that it is normal that desktop and smartphone browser doesn't receive notifications if it are closed.

My question is, what is it the advantage to build PWA with push-notification if we are not able to information our users to new event in the PWA ??? I beleive PWA was better than hybrid-app's. But maybe note... hybrid-app's can't be display on desktop browser but notification will work on smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a PWA problem but this is related ti how your OS manage browsers' push notification.

In Linux I see push notification also after browser close.